# Generated .pro file from visual studio Qt addin adds unnecessary openGL libraries?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, opengl, makefile

I've created a basic app in visual studio with Qt and an openGL widget. I export a .pro file from the addin so that I can compile in Linux.

I get the message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopengl32
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglu32
```

... when running make.

The issue goes away and the program compiles fine if I remove:

```
LIBS += -lopengl32 \
    -lglu32
```

... from the generated .pro file.

I understand the "export .pro" feature is not flawless, but is this the correct way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite remember the exact name of the OpenGL library on Linux, but it's not opengl32. Rather libopengl. So it's perfectly normal.

This will make you link with opengl32.lib on windows only:

```
win32 : LIBS += -lopengl32 -lglu32
```

and if needed, this will make you link with libopengl on Linux :

```
unix : LIBS += -lopengl -lglu
```

For the `macx` platform scope, I guess there is additional work to link with the OpenGL Framework.

Comment: Thank you, in the Qt .pro file I already specify that it should load the openGL module, and I assume it will load the platform-specific libraries for me. It seems to be that the visual studio project file must include those windows libraries, so it tries to put them in the  make file even though the Qt module will include the correct ones automatically.

Comment: Ok, so you just have to have `QT += core gui opengl` and `win32 : LIBS += -lopengl32 -lglu32`, is that right ?

Comment: The win32 libs can be omitted entirely it seems since qmake would add the correct libs to the generated Makefile on any system.